# Is there a way to get eclipse not to open/show auto generated code

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to get eclipse not to open/show auto generated code when it is being generated.

Example: If I use ctrl+1 to crete a new method/class/variable then I do not want focus to change at all. And I do not want eclipse to open the newly created class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not configurable today.

Comment: Sad -( but now I can at least stop looking for that setting.